# 'std::bad_alloc' in Java program

Tags: java, jvm-crash, alloc

I have a java process which I startup and let run for several days. The logs for this process looked fine up until the very end of the process's lifetime where I see the following two lines, and then nothing after it.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

There is supposed to be some shutdown logic which is executed when the process ends, but these two log lines are all I see.

What is the cause of this `std::bad_alloc` error? I've seen several other posts regarding this error but they are all from C++ programmers, whereas I am using Java, not C++. Does this indicate a bug in the JVM, or is it a consequence of some JVM related error such as an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: is your code using some dlls or similar libs written in c/c++??

Comment: sounds like a small memory leak and the operating system is telling jvm there was a problem trying to allocate memory.

Answer (score 2):

You've run out of native memory (which is distinct from the java heap). To fix this, you'd need to understand which code of yours (or jars on your classpath) are using C++ under the hood and making sure that things are being gc'd in a timely fashion.

For example, if you weren't calling close you'd possibly run into the same issue:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html#close()

Comment: Is it c++ I would have thought it to be c

Comment: C doesn't have a scope resolution operator